# How to force attachment size for every post

Tags: uploads, attachments, images

I created a custom size like this :

```
add_image_size( 'my-size', 615, 9999 );
```

Is there anyway i can force the ATTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS SIZE to be always ('my-size') for every attachment?

Comment: what do you mean "force the ATTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS SIZE to be always ('my-size') for every attachment"??

Comment: Do you mean the output of those images in the template or the actual files that are uploaded?

Comment: The output of the images

Comment: Is it possible to specify the size of the image rendered by the_content();?